# MongoDB Compass is getting stuck on a white screen after only a few seconds of use

Tags: mongodb, archlinux, mongodb-compass

I recently started learning MongoDB, and initially, I had no problems with Compass. However, after updating all packages using `yay`, Compass started malfunctioning.

When I run it, I first see a white screen, then the normal home page, but as soon as I try to move my mouse, the white screen reappears. I've tried refreshing the app, deleting and reinstalling a git version, and even manually deleting all Compass files, but I'm still experiencing the issue.

```
$ mongodb-compass --version
MongoDB Compass 1.40.2
```

Refreshing the app   (Ctrl+Shift+R)

Deleting and reinstalling a git version   `$ yay -r mongodb-compass`  `yay mongodb-compass-git`

Manually deleting all Compass files
`$ sudo rm -r /home/byalykt/.cache/yay/mongodb-compass`
`$ sudo rm -r /usr/bin/mongodb-compass` `$ sudo rm -r /usr/lib/mongodb-compass`
`$ sudo rm -r /usr/share/applications/mongodb-compass.desktop`
`$ sudo rm -r /usr/share/licenses/mongodb-compass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest working version is v1.39.4. We can't use `yay` to install a specific version, so you need to manually download the `PKGBUILD`.

1. Uninstall `mongodb-compass`:

```
sudo pacman -Rs mongodb-compass
```

2. Create a new folder and a file called `PKGBUILD` with the following content:

https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=mongodb-compass&id=f681e3b15b0a946a584250d6f2499b0c9b2e102f

3. Build and install:

```
makepkg -si
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an issue with the latest version. Version v1.39.0 worked perfectly fine after install [link gere](https://github.com/mongodb-js/compass/releases/tag/v1.39.0)

Comment: Is there a possibility to install that version with yay specifically?